# Filtering LiDAR points by elevation/height

Tags: arcgis-pro, lidar, point-cloud

I am trying to prepare training data for a deep learning model. The objective is to be able to identify trees in an urban area. Properly classifying the points in my training data would be a lot easier, I think, if there were a way to filter points based on their Z values. I am using ArcGIS Pro but would be open alternative open source methods. Pro seems only to allow filtering based on returns and class codes, but not point attributes.

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS Pro has tools to classify ground points, building roofs, and also a tool to classify by height. I would run the rough classification in the order I just mentioned as:

> Reclassifies lidar points based on their height from the ground surface.
> This tool reclassifies LAS points with class code values of 0 or 1 based on their height from the ground surface created using LAS points with class code values of 2, 8, or both 2 and 8. The American Society for Photogrammetry and Remote Sensing defines the LAS format specifications with a definition for class code that assigns 2 for ground and 8 for model key in LAS versions prior to 1.4. Model key classification was traditionally used to identify a subset of ground points. At LAS version 1.4, the model key designation was made into a classification flag which can be applied to any class code, and the definition for a class code value of 8 was reserved for later use.

> If the LAS data does not have any ground classified points, use the Classify LAS Ground tool. If the ground points use values other than 2 or 8, use the Change LAS Class Codes tool to reclassify the ground points accordingly.

> Classifying points using height gradients from the ground surface can provide a useful way to visualize and filter the point cloud which can also aid the process of conducting more refined interactive classification. The tool defaults to classifying class codes 3, 4, and 5, which represent low, medium and high vegetation in the ASPRS specification for the LAS format.

The documentation can be found with [this link](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/classify-las-building.htm).